# browser default home page unable to change/set for http://www.hao123.com/?tn=97473572_hao_pg

Tags: internet-explorer, url, browser

After installing Qvod player, my IE homepage was set to:

`http://www.hao123.com/?tn=97473572_hao_pg`

I tried to set the home page via IE settings, however it changed back to `http://www.hao123.com` again. After that, I discovered I have to check on regedit on both path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\Main and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet\Explorer\Main
```

for `Default_Page_URL`

I found my `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` setting Default_Page_URL to `hao123.com` and I quickly changed it to blank. After this, I was able to set the IE homePage to blank but the default page to appear when i click to start up IE, was `hao123.com`!

I also checked on right click> property of my IE shortcut, no default homepage are set.

After this, I uninstalled Qvod player, and it still didn't work!

Comment: Sounds like spyware / malware was installed on your computer.  Suggest you ask this on Super User - http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the QVOD folder, rename QvodExtend.dll to another name, then restart the computer, go to the control panel uninstall the QVOD.

Go to Qvod directory, completely remove all files, then restart your IE, hao123 is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am unable to remove all the Qvod directory (it is protected file), I had rename every .dll in my Qvod directory and restart my computer.

Finally it works! Thanks reneteh.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Locate the DLL file called 'QvodAddr.dll', rename it to 'QvodAddr.dll.bak'.

Step 2: Remove the 'http://www.hao123.com/?tn=97473572_hao_pg' from the Internet Explorer --> Internet Options --> General (Tab) --> Home page.

Step 3: Restart your Internet Explorer.

I use this to solve my problem. Hope it helps you.